# Elements of a split string array can't be used as function inputs?

Tags: java, arrays, input, split

Here is my code:

```
// This is the bug - this works.
String[] lst = {"desk", "pencil"};
String lst0 = lst[0];
System.out.println("path: " + lst[0]);
System.out.println("result: " + root.getDirectory(lst0).getFileName());

// This is the bug - this doesn't work.
String[] ef = "desk/pencil".split("/");
String ef1 = ef[0];
System.out.println("path: " + ef1);
System.out.println("result (without getFileName): " + root.getDirectory(ef1));
```

But in the second case, the function isn't called properly, as ef[0] seems considered differently from lst[0] by the compiler despite both being strings. I assume this is becaue lst is a array that resulted from list splitting. Is there any way to fix/work around this?

Comment: Have you used a debugger? What is the difference between the first way and second way?

Comment: What about the results are different?

Comment: Why are you calling `getFileName` in the first case but not the second?

Comment: Are the results, in fact, the same when you call `getFileName` in the second example? And, when you print `path` are `ef1` and `lst[0]` different?